# Perl Script Writes Labels on Several Lines

Tags: perl

So my code is this

```
print "<div id=\"form\">\n";
print "<form name=\"confirm\" method=post ACTION=\"\">\n";

print"<label for=\"name\">Name:</label>\n";
print "<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" class='forminput' id='name' value=\"$name\">\n";

print"<label for=\"amount\">£:</label>\n";
print "<input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" class='forminput' id='amount' value=\"$amount\">\n";

print"<label for=\"comment\">Comment:</label>\n";
print "<input type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" class='forminput' id='comment' value=\"$comment\">\n";


print "</form>\n";
```

The output is as follows 
Name: [TextBox] £:
[TextBox] Comment:
[TextBox]

Is it possible to write the perl to write the labels infront of the right text boxes?

Comment: That's a lot of backslashes.  You might want to look into alternative string delimiters in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) -- e.g., `qq{<label for="foo">$stuff</label>}` or even a here-doc.

Comment: This really hardly has anything to do with perl, and yet isn't even tagged with html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `<br>` after each line your want in a new line, something like this

```
print "<div id=\"form\">\n";
print "<form name=\"confirm\" method=post ACTION=\"\">\n";

print"<label for=\"name\">Name:</label><br>\n";
print "<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" class='forminput' id='name' value=\"$name\"><br>\n";

print"<label for=\"amount\">£:</label><br>\n";
print "<input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" class='forminput' id='amount' value=\"$amount\"><br>\n";

print"<label for=\"comment\">Comment:</label><br>\n";
print "<input type=\"text\" name=\"comment\" class='forminput' id='comment' value=\"$comment\"><br>\n";

print "</form>\n";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That brings the label on top of each text box!
ill have a look into it some more. thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

This seems more of an HTML & CSS question, but this would work:

```
print qq{
<div id="form">
<form name="confirm" method=post ACTION="">
<p><label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" class='forminput' id='name' value="$name"></p>
<p><label for="amount">£:</label>
<input type="text" name="amount" class='forminput' id='amount' value="$amount"></p>
<p><label for="comment">Comment:</label>
<input type="text" name="comment" class='forminput' id='comment' value="$comment"></p>
</form>
};
```

You could use some CSS to style it a bit more, and here's a guide on that:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/forms/article.php/3888746/HTML-Forms-From-Basics-to-Style-Layouts.htm